# Ancient Greek Translation: A response to Sappho's 146

Tags: ancient-greek, sappho, greek-translation, greek-to-english-translation

Thank you for reading.

Context: I'm designing an engagement ring for my partner, who has expressed her love of both Sappho's fragment #146 ( "Μήτ’ ἔμοι μέλι μήτε μέλισσα"/"For me neither the honey nor the bee" ) and of 17th century poesy rings ([example](https://www.tsbrown.com/pages/the-history-behind-poesy-rings)). I would like to design an engagement ring which has engraved on its inner surface a personal reply to Sappho's fragment: "Thou art for me/ Both the honey and the bee". How might this be translated into Sappho's Greek? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically we just need to replace the "neither ... nor" with an "and", and add "you [are]". The result might look like this:

> σὺ ἔμοι μέλι καὶ μέλισσα

This does, however, destroy the Sapphic meter. If you care about that, you could make a couple of slight changes as follows:

> σύ γ᾽ ἔμοι μέλι καὶ σὺ μέλισσα

This version preserves the lyric meter of the original (xx -uu-uu-u). There isn't a difference in meaning between the two versions except that the second repeats the "you": "You to me [are] honey and you [are] the bee".